# Temperature controller using pt-1000 sensor

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, control-theory

I need to control the temperature of a system with high accuracy with error value of $0.1$ degrees celsius +-. I will be using temperature sensor PT-1000. I need to know what would be the best option to use as a controller. The controller will control the fan which is used for cooling the system. The system is not actually a big system. It's a size of a small box. There is as such no high power concentrated heat source. Just need to stabilize the temperature of the system with high accuracy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Engineering. Your question is quite challenging, and it depends largely on the size of the system and the uniformity of the air in the system. For example, is the system a room, or a small box? Are there any high power concentrated heat sources that create uneven temperature fluctuations? Have you decided on how to pumped out/in heat in the system?  Please, update the question with more information, so that you get a more relevant answer.

Comment: Hi @NMech.Well the system is not actually a big system. It's a size of a small box. There is as such no high power concentrated heat sources. For cooling i would need a small fan and the temperature sensor used would be PT-1000. i just need to stabilize the temperature for e.g the temperature of the system needs to be of room temperature and i need to determine the temperature controller to interface with the PT-1000 sensor and fan.

Comment: So basically, what you are planning to do is control the fan speed?  In order to push in more air at ambient temperature, in order to keep the temperature constant?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you could take a look at my answer here [Is there any other controller than PID Controller?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36941/is-there-any-other-controller-than-pid-controller/36953#36953) . It kind of deals with the fact of the various controllers out there.

The problem of the best controller to use is something really debatable. The best controller always depends on what you have to control and in most cases the engineer has to design some, based upon the specifications that have been set, and afterwards decide which best fits the particular physical system.

As I understand from your question you only care about the temperature error, which means you only care about the steady state error of the system and you don't care about the time it takes for your system to reach the desired reference temperature. Considering this, you should go for controllers which take care of the steady state error like the PID for example. Even if this control scheme may look simple it can handle situations like the one you are refering to. I don't know your background at control theory which makes it more difficult to answer the question but if you have some basic background you should consider inserting a steady state error specification. Based on what you want I encourage you to add this specification:

$$ |e_{ss}| \leq 0.1 $$

However, this requires that you have a mathematical model of your system and then work out the math in order to come up with the controller gains that satisfy the above specification.

To sum up, I believe nobody can tell you that this is the best controller, go on and use it. Generally, you need to test some of those that can achieve great performance regarding the steady state error of your system like PID, lag-compensator, dynamic state feedback and many more. Based on your background you could also go for model predictive control or even adaptive controllers which will certainly achieve great performance. You could start from the PID control scheme and I am sure you can tune the gains in such way to satisfy your requirements. Keep in mind that you can tune the PID gains even if you don't have a mathematical model of the system, a fact which makes it even simpler.

Finally, I would like to point out that the sensor you are using doesn't play such an important role to the selection of the controller. You should consider its characteristics in order to design a noise attenuation filter for example if needed or take care of a potential measurement inaccuracy it may show.